# are AutoIt string variables binary safe? can i store binary data there?

Tags: string, autoit

(SO won't let me post without a body even though the entire question is in the title)

are AutoIt string variables binary safe? can i safely store binary data in them? (unlike, say, Python or JavaScript string variables)

Answer (score 0):

testing suggest that yes, autoit string variables are binary safe, if you do

```
$test="";
for $i = 0 To 255
   $test = $test & Chr($i);
Next
ConsoleWrite(StringLen($test));
```

the string will contain every byte, however some builtin functions are not binary safe, for example ConsoleWrite() will stop writing on the first null byte, so adding `ConsoleWrite($test);` will print absolutely nothing. i have requested a fix for that here https://www.autoitscript.com/trac/autoit/ticket/3764 , but in the meantime, here is a binary-safe implementation of ConsoleWrite:

```
; binary safe ConsoleWrite()  ( AutoIt's builtin ConsoleWrite() is not binary safe, it chokes if you try to write a null byte to stdout)
Func ConsoleWriteBinarySafe( Const ByRef $str)
   Local $bytesWritten=0;
   Local $stdoutHandle=_WinAPI_GetStdHandle(1);
   Local $tBuffer = DllStructCreate("byte[" & StringLen($str) & "]");
   DllStructSetData($tBuffer, 1, $str);
   _WinAPI_WriteFile ( $stdoutHandle, $tBuffer, StringLen($str), $bytesWritten);
   return $bytesWritten;
EndFunc
```